# Appending to parent, show all checkbox values

Tags: javascript

I have some checkboxes and once you check some of them and click on a button, I need to show them in a span ( dynaically created ) when I try to display multiple values of it (label vals) , only the last one is getting displayed. I want output something like that in the console.

Please find fiddle link for the reference code

```
let spanTopic =  document.createElement('span');
var topicSelected = document.getElementById('topicCheckContainer').getElementsByTagName('input');
for( let i=0 ; i<topicSelected.length;i++){
    if(topicSelected[i].checked){
        var myValueofTopic = topicSelected[i].parentNode.getElementsByTagName("LABEL")[i].innerHTML;
        console.log(myValueofTopic);
        spanTopic.innerHTML = "Observation Topic Selected : " + myValueofTopic;   
    }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/karantewari/acomtxbg/

Check more than one checkboxes and click on the button, you can see only the last one is getting displayed whereas in the console I can see the other codes.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you change the value of the span each time the for expression is looping. It causes that you erase the previous value in each loop.

You can see in console that you have all the texts from input you checked but not on the same line which means that each line refers to a single console log. You want to have it all on the same line.

To solve the problem, just add "+" before you assign the value with innerHTML:

```
spanTopic.innerHTML += "Observation Topic Selected : " + myValueofTopic;
```

"+=" is a shortwriting way to concatenate a value to an already existing value but you can also write `x = x + y`

Comment: Right, that does solve the issue, well I figured out this well that I'm erasing the values here. Thanks for the help @qwsd.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is pretty much alright buddy.. Just a tiny overlook I guess.

The part where you set the value of the `<span>` tag, you need to APPEND new contents to the old ones. Instead you are replacing it. Hence the issue. Just replace the `=` with `+=` and it should work.

I have also added a new line at the end of each line to improve the look of it.

[Click this link for the working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rdfs95q0/1/)

Or take a look at the snippet below:

```
spanTopic.innerHTML += "<br>Observation Topic Selected : " + myValueofTopic; //observe the +=
```

```js
function myAdditionFrame() {
  let spanTopic = document.getElementById('spanID');
  if (typeof(spanTopic) != 'undefined' && spanTopic != null) {
    spanTopic.innerHTML = ""; //If the span tag is already filled with some previous click action, empty it for the next click.
  } else {
    spanTopic = document.createElement('span');
    spanTopic.setAttribute("id", 'spanID');
  }
  var topicSelected = document.getElementById('topicCheckContainer').getElementsByTagName('input');
  for (let i = 0; i < topicSelected.length; i++) {
    if (topicSelected[i].checked) {
      var myValueofTopic = topicSelected[i].parentNode.getElementsByTagName("LABEL")[i].innerHTML;
      //console.log(myValueofTopic);
      spanTopic.innerHTML += "Observation Topic Selected : " + myValueofTopic + "<br>";
    }
  }
  document.getElementById('obserDetailsComeHere').appendChild(spanTopic);
}
```

```html
<div class="obserDetailsComeHere" id="obserDetailsComeHere">

</div>
<div class="checkbox-primary" id="topicCheckContainer">
  <input type="checkbox" id="myObserInput"><label for="myObserInput">Topic #1 Lore dolor sit amet.</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="myObserInput1"><label for="myObserInput1">Topic #2 Loresum dolor sit amet.</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="myObserInput2"><label for="myObserInput2">Topic #3 lor sit amet.</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="myObserInput3"><label for="myObserInput3">Topic #4 Lorem ipor sit amet.</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="myObserInput4"><label for="myObserInput4">Topic #5 Loredolor sit amet.</label><br>
</div>
<button onclick="myAdditionFrame()">
                        Click
                        </button>
```

Comment: thanks for the help , thats what I was looking for and yes there was this minor error which was bothering me. Thanks for the fiddle link too :)

Comment: And from what I've seen @KaranTewari, it keeps printing the "Observation Topic Selected" one below the other every time you press the `click` button.. Hence I've updated the code in the fiddle to replace it with the latest clicked items..

Comment: yea for that I've created a that seperately now and then append the myValueofTopic to it, so it comes properly now and without repeating the "Observation Topic Selected"